# Open Remote Modal automatically or when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, onload

I'm trying to load a remote page (on same server) in a Modal automatically when a page loads. I have tried multiple ways with no luck.

```
$('#globalRemoteModal').modal();
$('#globalRemoteModal').modal('show');
$('#globalRemoteModal').modal('togle');
$('#globalRemoteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var loadurl = $(e.relatedTarget).data('/remote.php? 
   value=data&value2=data2');
   $(this).find('.modal-content').load(loadurl);
});
```

I am able to get the Modal to work via a click on a link, but need it to load automatically....

Comment: Are you want to display modal on page load?

Comment: Yes, I found a new way of getting the final results that I was looking for and better for the user. Might come back to the problem later and try to explain what I was trying to do.